# QML - Need idea how to animate waves

Tags: qt, animation, svg, qml

In my QML game I have some water space with waves above it. I need an idea how to animate waves. I just need some simple animation when wave goes up and down. I've tried animated `SVG` both with `Image` and `AnimatedImage`. Nothing works. `GIF` looks not so good due to color limitation. May be some graphical effect or sprites? Any idea will be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code creates a continuous wave animation for an Image, by using a
[sine wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave) formula.

```
Image {
    id: sourceImg
    anchors.fill: parent
    source: "../images/src.png"
    visible: false
}

ShaderEffect {
    anchors.fill: parent
    property variant source: sourceImg
    property real frequency: 1
    property real amplitude: 0.1
    property real time: 0.0
    NumberAnimation on time {
        from: 0; to: Math.PI*2; duration: 10000; loops: Animation.Infinite
    }
    fragmentShader: "
                    varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;
                    uniform sampler2D source;
                    uniform lowp float qt_Opacity;
                    uniform highp float frequency;
                    uniform highp float amplitude;
                    uniform highp float time;
                    void main() {
                        highp vec2 texCoord = qt_TexCoord0;
                        texCoord.y = amplitude * sin(time * frequency + texCoord.x * 6.283185) + texCoord.y;
                        gl_FragColor = texture2D(source, texCoord) * qt_Opacity;
                    }"
}
```

Comment: thanks @Blastings that's close to my goal. I just need to adopt it to tiled image, it still does not work for me. Don't you think the shader will cause to overload for CPU?

Comment: So you have several images arranged in a tile grid? 
As far as I know the QML shader code should run on the GPU and not the CPU.